# How to select all elements from a table in sqlite where a value X is within a certain radius R from another value C?

Tags: sql, sqlite

The table in question is very large, and this select function could be called very often over a short amount of time.

As the title suggests, given a center integer value C and a radius integer value R, how can I access all rows within a db file such that the row integer values X in column Cx satisfy |x-C|<R?

i.e.

1. | 15
2. | 12
3. | 17
4. | 16
5. | 13
6. | 9

C=10, R=3 => 2, 6

Preferably ordered by closest to C value, but if not possible or it increases asymptotic time complexity then not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the abs function

```
select * from table_name
where abs(col1 - C ) < R;
```